# Hide certain Iphone apps "More iPhone Apps by"

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

In the Itunes Store when someone views my XYZ app they can see everything I have created with my developer account. Is there any way to remove a specific application that I developed from the "More iPhone Apps by " list ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if there is any information lacking in your question. If your app is approved, then you cannot hide it. If you remove the app from the Store (it doesn't mean you delete the app), it should disappear from the list of "more iPhone apps by..." since it will no longer be available on the Store. There is no other way you could customize the apps that appear.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's just that I don't want some of my apps to be associated with the others, but I guess there's no way to change that.

Comment: There's no way. You should transfer the apps that you don't want connected with the rest of them to another dev account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming